# Dryer got rained on

Tags: dryer, rain

Our dryer was left outdoors overnight and it rained. Should we be concerned about it shorting if we plug it back in?

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .

Comment: Then I'm concerned, thanks :) Do I let it dry a few days? Give up and replace it?

Comment: Just to clarify, tell us more about what type of "dryer" you speak of.  Most people reading this in North America will visualize a clothes dryer, which is a large bulky appliance.  Your profile indicates you are from Jerusalem however, so it's possible you're referring to something else.

Comment: @Tyson Similar to the clothes dryers I've used in the US. This one was manufactured in Germany.

Comment: Having spent a few months in Beersheva, I can say that the usual result of an Israeli rain storm is that everything is _really_ wet, then about 30 minutes later, everything is back to bone dry, with the only remaining sign of the rainfall is all the beautiful flowers blooming. Once it dries, it shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: So we just bought a top loader washer and dryer from someone and it was in the back of our truck overnight and we had them covered with a tarp then it came off during the storm are they runied now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dryers are designed for dry locations , but with that said they are usually close to a water supply and drain. I have not seen a dryer that if wiped dry would not be fine to run after getting some rain. Or being doused by an overflowing drain / washer supply line that bursts. A wipe down and moving it back inside I would expect it to be fine.

Comment: Agreed, but I'd still let it sit for a couple days to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I'd let it dry out for a day or two. Your biggest risk from being outside is *condensation*, and that will get into everything.